# jQuery drag and retain it same place

Tags: jquery, html

Tplease refer my fiddle

```
 $("#header").draggable({
   // helper: "clone",
    //cursor: 'move',
     containment: '#list ul'
});
```

[Refer this fiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/BKxQ7/1/)

By drag the image field  i want to place it in test1, test2 or test3.

Also how to get the li id of the image placed.

If i drag this image field to test1. then the image field should retain it its position. So only i can drag this and drop to test2 also. Now i couldn't able to place this image field more than one place. Also i don't know how to remove this after drop. Please help me Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BKxQ7/5/)

Use this Script in ur code:

```
$("#header").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

        $("#container").droppable({

            drop: function (e, ui) {

                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();
                x.draggable({
                    helper: 'original',
                    containment: '#container',
                    tolerance: 'fit'
                });

                x.appendTo('#container');
            }

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: If we set revert to true, then the image field will not be placed in the test1, test2, test3. I want to place it in test1,2,3 li like the clone process.

Comment: i update my post try the above script it is working.

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. 
I used this command   var droppableId = $(this).attr("id"); to get the li id of the dropped section. but i couldn't. What i am doing wrong here.